# How to listen floating keyboard show and hide notifications on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, ipados

How to listen floating keyboard show and hide on iPad? `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` won't be called back. Main code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad() {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // NOT called back
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide {
    // NOT called back
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it call back ? can you provide how you use it ?

Comment: @King.lbt Just normal use, working well on non-floating keyboard iOS devices. Additional info attached in content.

Answer (score 0):

The standard keyboard `willShow` and `willHide` do not work with a floating keyboard on iPad. Instead, we can observe the `willChangeFrame` notification, and look at the beginning and end frame to determine if the keyboard will appear or hide.

Here's an example in swift:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardFrameWillChange), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification.rawValue), object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardFrameWillChange() {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyBoardEndRect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    let keyBoardBeginRect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! CGRect

    if (keyBoardBeginRect.equalTo(CGRect.zero)) {
        // Floating keyboard will show        
    }

    if (keyBoardEndRect.equalTo(CGRect.zero)) {
        // Floating keyboard will hide        
    }
}
```